# Distinct Count after Sum

Tags: tableau-api

So I am looking to do a count after aggregation. Basically I want to be able to total up the Inventory count with a sum and then count how many times each employee has a non zero inventory count.

So for this data Jack/Jimmy would have a count of 1, Sam would have a count of 2 and Steve would have a count of 0. I could easily do this in SQL on the back end but I also want them to be able to use a date parameter. So if they shifted the date to only 1/1/17 Sam would have a count of 1 and everyone else would have a 0. Any help would be much appreciated!

### Data

```
Emp          Item          Inventory     Date
Sam          Crackers       1          1/1/2017
Jack         Crackers       1          1/1/2017
Jack         Crackers      -1          2/1/2017
Jimmy        Crackers      -2          1/1/2017
Sam          Apples         1          1/1/2017
Steve        Apples        -1          1/1/2017
Sam          Cheese         1          1/1/2017
```

### With Date>= '1/1/17':

```
Emp  NonZeroCount
Sam      2  
Jack     1
Jimmy    1
Steve    0
```

### With Date = '1/1/17':

```
Emp  NonZeroCount
Sam      1  
Jack     0
Jimmy    0
Steve    0
```

### SQL I envision it replacing

```
Create Table #Test(
Empl varchar(50),
Item Varchar (50),
Inventory int,
Date Date
)

Declare @DateParam Date 
Set @DateParam = '1/1/17'

Insert into #Test (Empl,Item,Inventory,Date)
Values
('Sam','Crackers',1,'1/1/2017'),
('Jack','Crackers',1,'1/1/2017'),
('Jack','Crackers',-1,'2/1/2017'),
('Jimmy','Crackers',-2,'1/1/2017'),
('Sam','Apples',1,'1/1/2017'),
('Steve','Apples',-1,'1/1/2017'),
('Sam','Cheese',1,'1/1/2017');

Select
Item,Sum(Inventory) as Total
into #badItems
from #Test
Where Date >= @DateParam
group by Item
having Sum(Inventory) <> 0

Select
T.Empl,Count(Distinct BI.Item)
From #Test T
Inner Join #badItems BI on BI.Item = T.Item
group by T.Empl
```

Comment: The numbers in your example don't seem to add up to the amounts you claim in your description. Or at least, the problem description is still unclear to me. If you think it is easy in SQL, try showing the SQL that does what you want, and I can then understand your goal enough to show the Tableau equivalent.

Comment: So I added the SQL. It does the exact logic I desire but the problem is I need them to be able to adjust @DateParam in Tableau and it gives different results for 1/1/17 and 2/1/17

Comment: The SQL helps explain what you want, but can you verify your sample results above in the section titled "With Date Set to 1/1/2017:"? I can reproduce the results with Tableau for the the "With No Date Set" case. Since you have a ">= @DateParam" in your query instead of a ">", I wonder if you meant With Date Set to 1/2/2017? (else it seems the same as the With No Date Case). If you do that, the results I get show 1 for Jack and Jimmy instead of 0, since both bought Crackers. Is the problem statement wrong? (Just don't want to solve the wrong problem)

Comment: Sorry that "date set to 1/1/17" was before I had it in the SQL example. So I meant actually putting the date to 1/1/17 which in this case would be "Where Date >= '1/1/17'. Hope that answers the question?

Comment: I figured that, but wouldn't the SQL give the same result in both your test cases since every date in your test set is >= 1/1/2017? I suspect your second set of expected results is wrong. Either that, or I'm still missing something about what you are trying to do.

Comment: There is 1 '2/1/17' crackers. So if you say Date = '1/1/17' it would change crackers to 0 total inventory which trickles down to everything else. Basically my phrasing did not match up well with my SQL.

Comment: If you say Date EQUALS 1/1/17 then you get 0 as you say. If you say Date GREATER THAN OR EQUAL TO 1/1/17, then you get an inventory of -1

Comment: I updated the question headers to now make sense :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good case for creating a set in Tableau.

Select the Item field in the data pane on the left, and right click to create a set based on that field. Name it Bad Items, and define it using the following formula on the Condition tab, which assumes you've defined a parameter named [DateParam] of type Date.

```
sum(if [Date] >= [DateParam] then [Inventory] end) <> 0
```

You can then use the set on the filter shelf, row shelf, in calculations or combine with other sets as desired.

[image]

P.S. I used an alias to display the text "Bad Items" instead of "In" in the table, set a manual default sort order for the Emp field (in case you are trying to reproduce this exactly)